# What does it mean, "lick of confidence"?

Tags: word-meaning

> Halsey: So, McClusky, you are now in charge of the air group. I don't
>   have a **lick of confidence** in those damn torpedoes.

I find this line in movie Midway 2019.

What does it mean, "lick of confidence"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*A lick of something is a small amount of it.* ([Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/lick))

**Examples:**

1. The living room could do with a lick of paint.
2. Those kids don't have a lick of common sense

A lick of confidence: a small amount of confidence.